# What's the simplest way to pull from master and merge it to your branch?

Tags: git

It's not that it's a huge pain, but I feel like I'm probably not doing this in the most optimal way possible:

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout my_feature_branch
$ git merge master
$ git stash apply
```

Is there a simpler way to do the above, preferably without needing to stash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing a straight merging, why the stash?  Could you not just do:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

Where `origin` is the name of your remote repo.

This doesn't update your local `master` branch, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git pull --rebase` assuming you want your feature branch to be downstream from `origin/master` and you haven't made your feature branch commits public.

You can skip the stash step and git will complain if it can't merge if any of the commits contain modifications to the files that are dirty in your working directory.